# How can I format and humanize a video chunk duration using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to correctly display a duration with moment.js, but I can't find the right way to do it.

I have two events, `start` and `stop`. Both record in a variable a video current time, in seconds (e.g. 254.36 and 428.12).

First, I want to display the start and stop time. I achieve that like this:

```
var startTime = 12345; //let's say it is my start time in seconds
moment.utc(startTime *1000).format("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

Second, I want to display the duration between start and stop in a human readable way. For example, if `stopTime - startTime === 94,23` seconds, I want to:

- omit the milliseconds. I could just use `Math.round()` on my subtraction result but I want to know if it can be done using moment.js.
- present it in an accurate formated version. I started with something like that:

  ```
  moment.duration(stopTime - startTime , "seconds").humanize();
  ```

  but it will display 'a few seconds' if I have, for instance, a 4 second input. If I have a `stopTime - startTime === 94,23` seconds, I would like to display something like: 1 minute and 34 seconds (and omit the minute if it lasts less than a minute).

Again, I could avoid using moment.js but I want to take advantage of the localization features, learn what can and cannot be done and how to use it properly.

Comment: As I know there are no native way for momentjs to display only significant values, so try write small function to get right output format for different range values

Comment: @Ivan, you're right, that's a duplicate. I already quickly read the question, but I missed the essential. This is more or less my answer. I voted to close.